# while loop in bash until file size does not change

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to do the following while loop using a bash script

```
file_size = 0
temp_size = 1
output_file
while (file_size != temp_size)
     temp_size = file_size
     download file
     append to output_file if possible
     file_size = sizeof(output_file)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please read up on bash scripting, _try_ something then post a question if you have specific problems.

Answer (score 6):

It's unclear what exactly you are looking for, but I've taken a shot in hopes that this will help you.

The following program needs to be placed in a text file.  Let's say you name it `dl`.  You need to change it's permissions with

```
chmod u+x dl
```

You run it by passing in the output file name you are looking for.

```
./dl output
```

It downloads the image file, at the url I hard coded in, over and over appending the output to the output file until the size of the output file is equal to or greater than the size that you specify in the `temp_size` variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

STAT="stat -c%s"
if [ $(uname) == "Darwin" ]; then
  STAT="stat -f%z"
fi

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 output_filename"
  exit 1
fi

output_file="$1"
file_size=$($STAT "$output_file")
temp_size=1000000
download_file="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/franz_kafkas_130th_birthday-1976005-hp.png"
while [[ $file_size -le $temp_size ]]; do
  wget -O - $download_file >> "$output_file"
  file_size=$($STAT "$output_file")
done
echo $output_file is now $file_size bytes.
```

If you run it again with the same parameter, it will do nothing because the output file is already larger than the temp_size.  You can reset it by giving it another file name, or removing the output file.

```
rm output
```

Comment: Why did  you rollback the `env`? Believe me, on this site you will get upvotes just for using that and it makes your script portable to any *nix like system. It is a good habit to get into.

Comment: You carefully enclosed the strings between double quotes but on some lines with `output_file` you forgot them which would disallow using filenames with spaces.